# react-navigation How to show Header over Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Contrary to other questions **I DO want my Header over the Drawer**, how do I go about solving this?

See the [docs' Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Drawer%20Navigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.0.6&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fdrawer-example.js), how can you edit it in order for the header to show over the Drawer (the burger menu would then be changed to a "< Back" Button to close it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I arrived at is to recreate the header with `react-native-paper` and just use it as a custom header.
The drawer then can be replaced to a custom drawer that contains the header.

This might be a bit more work but is the solution I came up with.